# Print diary pages in size in _letter_ instead of _A4_?

Tags: printing, emacs

How can I set up `emacs` to print monthly calendar pages in a size *other* than A4?

When printing diary pages from `emacs`, the default setting is A4 paper.

Comment: *How* do you print these pages? What Emacs command are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Probably by customizing the user option `lpr-switches` with:

```
   -o media=size
        Sets the page size to size. Most printers  support  at  least  the
        size names "a4", "letter", and "legal".
```

Which I've quoted from the `lpr` man page on my system.

n.b. I would expect `-o` and `media=size` to be two separate values in the list of switches.

To do this *only* for your diary file, you can set it as a file-local variable on the first line.  E.g.:

```
-*- lpr-switches: ("-o" "media=letter"); -*-
```

Calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `normal-mode` should pick up the change (or else kill the buffer and re-visit it).  Emacs should prompt you to approve the file-local value.